# Simple python query: properly setting up arcpy.env.workspace and defining datasets

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I'm creating a python script (for the first time in quite a long time). And the basics are confusing me a little. With the below code I keep getting the error:

"ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset /MARCHNET does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (AddField)."

[image]

In the "OK" folder there is a shapefile named MARCHNET and it is also currently open in an instance in ArcMap.

Comment: you should try:   PmsNet = "MARCHNET.shp"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to mention the extension.

If you are working with shapfiles in a workspace you always have to add the '.shp', such as here:

```
PmsNet = r'MARCHNET.shp'
```

You can work with the name alone *only* if your workspace is a geodatabase, as feature classes in a geodatabase do not have file extensions.